# Will my parents get residence card on visitor visa to Uk?

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa, pakistani-citizen, uk-visitor-visa

Can my parents obtain a residence card after entering the UK on visitor's visa?

Comment: On what basis do you think they could do this? Are you an EU citizen, for example? What is their citizenship, are they dependent on you?

Comment: I am marrying an eea citizen.

Comment: Are your parents dependent on you?

Comment: No they are not depeendent but they come under direct family members

Comment: They won’t qualify if they’re not dependent

Comment: they will qualify under euss scheme

Comment: ok i undertand yes they are dependent

Answer (score 1):

No, absolutely not. It is never possible (outside of a few narrow cases such as asylum seekers, and other exceptional situations) to switch from being a visitor to the UK to any other status. All applications for residence must be made from outside the UK.

Comment: I've downvoted this answer because a residence card is issued under the Immigration (EEA) Regulations, which take priority over the Immigration Rules (which govern visitor visas).  Someone who qualifies under the regulations can disregard any restrictions imposed under the rules; the regulations are explicit on that point.  In other words, this is one of the exceptional situations.  I don't have time to write an answer now, but I'm pretty sure I've written one in the last several months either here or at [Travel.SE], so the question might be a duplicate.

Comment: @phoog What is immigration regulation about and why it takes priority over the rules!!?!? I would write a question for that if you prefer.

Comment: I believe Jeffryes’s answer is correct so I upvote!

Comment: @Iman the regulations are the transposition of the European free movement directive into UK law.  This will persist until the end of the year.  It takes priority over the Immigration rules because the rights enumerated in the regulations are rights that derive from the EU treaties.  I'll try to find the answer I spoke of in my earlier comment and post a link.

Comment: @phoog Thanks, it was clear. But it looks like the OP is from a non-eu country (Pakistan-according to Tag). So the regulations are not applicable here, right?

Comment: @Iman OP is marrying an EEA citizen, so the regulations will apply to OP.  They will apply to OP's parents only if the parents are dependent.  Obviously if the parents don't qualify under the regulations, they won't be able to get a card.  But if they do, they will be able to get one after entering as visitors.